# onmouseup doesn't like being in group with a gradient

Tags: events, svg, gradient, onmouseup

I've made this little flag icon.

http://www.trjps.co.uk/image_store_old/estonia_flag.svg

When you mouseover, it lights up. When you click down it goes brighter (this is done by making an overlay gradient visible), and it moves a bit too.

Everything is controlled by a set of mouseon's, mouseouts's etc in the group tag

A problem occurs when the mouse is presses then moved. The second the pointer hits the overlay, a mouseup event occurs. The pointer has never left the group as the overlay is in the same group.

I even tried putting all the gradient stops in the group but without any change.

Am I overlooking something? Any help or hint is most appreciated.

Gaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's a browser bug. A sudden *mouse block* of an element shouldn't trigger a mouseup if that element is a child of the event element and event propagation is allowed.

You can work around this by manipulating `fill-opacity` instead of `visibility`:

```
   //remove  .setAttribute('visiblity', ...)
   onmousedown="getElementById('flash').setAttribute('fill-opacity',1)"
   onmouseup="getElementById('flash').setAttribute('fill-opacity',0)"
```

And your `#flash` element...

```
<!--Removed visibility="hidden" added fill-opacity="1" and removed fill-opacity:0 from styles -->
<path
     style="fill:url(#radialGradient3033);fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1.2529794;stroke-opacity:0"
     d="M 423.65326,432.06998 C 405.51096,436.96285 390.19952,445.00107 368.27826,447.66373 362.06308,452.02659 356.97847,456.99773 353.34076,462.22623 L 353.34076,496.06998 C 359.10138,502.25487 368.35017,506.24285 379.40326,507.60123 401.52711,502.8051 417.56662,493.26432 440.49701,490.66373 445.27742,487.01892 449.28524,482.98308 452.37201,478.78873 L 452.37201,443.19498 C 445.96886,436.83241 435.72653,432.94392 423.65326,432.06998 z"
     id="flash"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     fill-opacity="1"
 />
```

Comment: Bonza! This works a treat. I tried Firefox and opera with the problem code and both behaved the same (not often the case for SVG in my experience). And I often avoided 'fill-opacity' in favor of 'visibility' for some strange reason. Lesson learned. Thank you.